# Ошибка при выполнении программы

Tags: char, c, c++, printf

Учу Си по книге Стивена Прата "С. Лекции и Упражнения. 5-е издание".
**Так вот, выполняю упражнение для повторения**.

**Сама задача:**

> Напишите программу, которая использует
>   вызов функции printf() для печати
>   вашего имени и фамилии в одной строке,
>   использует второй вызов функции
>   printf(), чтобы напечатать ваше имя и
>   фамилию в двух строках, и использует
>   два вызова функции printf() для печати
>   вашего имени и фамилии в одной
>   строке. Выходные данные должны иметь
>   следующий вид (при этом используются
>   ваши персональные данные ):  Иван
>   Иванов Первый оператор печати  Иван
>   Второй оператор печати  Иванов Все
>   еще второй оператор печати Иван Иванов
>   Третий и четвертый операторы печати

**Собственно моё решение:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
 char name,name2;
 printf("HEllo, my name a Computer #3! And you?\n");
 scanf("%s,%s",&name,&name2);
 printf("Hello, %s %s",&name,&name2);
 printf("%s \n, %s",&name,&name2);
 printf("Hello, %s %s",name,name2);
 printf("I'm sorry, but not why you say what you know C");
 getch();
 return (0);   
}
```

**Все компилируется, запускается, а дальше вот что происходит:**

[image]

**Хорошо не мог бы ли кто предоставить другой вариант решения, я тут "погуглил" и понял что тип данных "строка" не предусмотрен, как же мне тогда быть? всегда писать "char name[30]" не пойдет.. А если например мне надо обработать тысячи таких имен и длина всех имен не известна за ранее !? Не надо писать мол учи дальше потом новые типы данных узнаешь поймешь, автор задачи не просто также её дал на этом уровне прохождения!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переменные `name` и `name2` у вас декларированы как `char`, а вы читаете строку - то есть выходите за границу аллоцированного под `name/name2` пространства - наказание за это неотвратимо :)

Comment: но когда я считываю как %c тоже не выходит...

Comment: Самое короткое имя и фамилию которую я знаю, содержит по две буквы (Ия Эм. Эм - это корейская фамилия, а Ия - вполне [себе имя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F)).). А char - это одна. Таких имен я не знаю.

Используйте `char name[30];` - этого под имя должно хватить (скорее всего).

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в данный момент лежит глубже.

Откровенно скажу, не знаю, что и в какой последовательности написано в учебнике Стивена Прата, но Вам надо повнимательней почитать о машинном представлении переменных разных типов (обратите внимание на их размер в байтах), массивах, указателях и символьных строках в Си.

А затем стоит прочесть описания форматов в `man 3 scanf` и `man 3 printf`.

**Обновление**

Не нравится 30, сделайте 1000. А вот причем здесь тысячи имен?

Ведь новые имена будут попадать в те же переменные, затирая старые.

Если же Вам потребуется хранить их все, то в копии можно хранить ровно столько байт (ну, плюс еще немного для "служебной информации"), сколько занимает конкретное имя (сейчас пока не буду описывать как именно это можно делать).

---

А может Вам лучше что-то другое почитать? Например, http://ermak.cs.nstu.ru/cprog/HTML/index.htm

Comment: Хорошо, не мог бы кто предоставить другой вариант решения, я тут "погуглил" и понял, что тип данных "строка" не предусмотрен, как же мне тогда быть? Всегда писать "char name[30]" не пойдет. А если, например, мне надо обработать тысячи таких имен и длина всех имен не известна заранее!? Не надо писать, мол, учи дальше, потом новые типы данных узнаешь, поймешь, автор задачи не просто также её дал на этом уровне прохождения!